# Is there an effective way to designing data intensive pipeline using Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, etl

Please I need some suggestions to something I have recently encountered.

- I have a ETL process that loads data into snowflake table `transactions table`. This table contains all transaction made (`errors, e_calls, responses, pa_info`). This table has about 70 billion records
- I need to be able to expose all  `responses` transactions in a view or table

Here are my thoughts:

- I can create the `responses` view from the `transaction table`, but my concern is, this may have some performance issues in terms of latency while querying the `responses` view
- I can set up a separate ETL job for loading only `responses` transactions into a `responses` table
- I can create a `responses` table which is loaded incrementally by `transaction` table  using streams and tasks. I am also trying to avoid using dynamic tables for now

Is there an effective way to do this, putting performance into considerations

Comment: You are on right path.
Just create cluster key for transaction_type, 
Once it's in place even normal view with filter will be sufficient. 
And if you want more performant than view check for materialized view

Comment: Many thanks for this

Comment: You need to look at how this table is being queried (by transaction type, by date, etc). Do you know that querying this table doesn't perform acceptably or are you just assuming it won't? The fact that the table has 70 billion may be irrelevant due to the way Snowflake does partition pruning in queries